# Find and swap two divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, find, swap

Currently working on a responsive website. When the window is resized to mobile I need to find and reorder some divs. Right now I'm doing it this way:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if( width < 768) {
    $('#id-1 .image-box').insertBefore($('#id-1 .text-box'));
    $('#id-2 .image-box').insertBefore($('#id-1 .text-box'));
    $('#id-3 .image-box').insertBefore($('#id-1 .text-box'));
  } else if( width > 767) {
    $('#id-1 .text-box').insertBefore($('#id-1 .image-box'));
    $('#id-2 .text-box').insertBefore($('#id-2 .image-box'));
    $('#id-3 .text-box').insertBefore($('#id-3 .image-box'));
  }
} );
$(window).resize();
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I need to search for a div, in this case '.image-box', check the class of the pervious div and if it is '.text-box' swap the two.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Anyway to see the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Pending the HTML, here's an approach that is a bit more scalable.

```
var elements = [
   $('#id-1'),
   $('#id-2'),
   $('#id-3')
];
var swap = function(firstSelector, secondSelector) {
    for ( var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; ++i ) {
        elements[i].find(firstSelector)
            .insertBefore(elements[i].find(secondSelector);
    }
};
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if( width < 768) {
    swap('.image-box', '.text-box');
  } else if( width > 767) {
    swap('.text-box', '.image-box');
  }
});
$(window).resize();
```